# Why does HasFlag extension method on Enum trump Enum.HasFlag?

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

If I create an extension method on Enum called `HasFlag`, whenever I try to call `HasFlag` on an enum instance, it uses the extension method, rather than the instance method. Why?

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
  public static bool HasFlag(this Enum e)
  {
    return false
  }
}
```

With code:

```cs
public enum Foo
{
  A, B, C
}

public void Whatever()
{
  Foo e = Foo.A;
  if (e.HasFlag())
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```cs
public void Whatever()
{
  Foo e = Foo.A;
  if (Extensions.HasFlag(e))
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the compiler use the `Enum.HasFlag` instance method?

Comment: Because the instance method `HasFlag` is expecting a parameter. Since you don't provide one, it resolves to the extension-method. Try `e.HasFlag(Foo.A);` and see.

Comment: Indeed, check the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782536(v=vs.110).aspx) and note the signature. It is different from your `HasFlag` function. Also, there's no point using `HasFlag` unless your enum is marked with the `FlagsAttribute`.

Comment: Yikes! I'm turning the computer off and going for a nice lie down. Thanks!

Comment: Nice interview question... ( an evil one hahaha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type. For client code written in C# and Visual Basic, there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

Extension methods cannot be override on instance main methods and it will not know which method to call:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods

The only way around this is to call your extension method using normal static method syntax. So instead of this:

```
e.HasFlag();
```

you would have to do this:

```
Extensions.HasFlag(e);
```

But if you add other parameters to your extension methods then it is not same to main methods, so when you call `HasFlag` method, the extension method called actually. For example:

```
public static bool HasFlag(this Enum e, bool isNullable)
{
    return false;
}
```

References:

[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Extension Methods, Nulls, Namespaces and Precedence in C#](http://gen5.info/q/2008/07/03/extension-methods-nulls-namespaces-and-precedence-in-c/)

Comment: Yep, I was being daft, and missed the parameters. Thanks!